# Integrate OneDrive and office online into a MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365, onedrive

How can integrate One Drive into an MVC application to allow users to upload documents and edit them online. I don't know if just consuming One Drive API will give me the chance to edit the documents with office online. Does anybody know what would be the right approach to meet this requirement. Where can I find examples showing how to edit documents online. Any ideas How can I approach this implementation?

Comment: https://dev.onedrive.com/SDKs.htm

Comment: I have got the OneDrive API documentation but I dont know what i can use to edit documents already stored on OndeDrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the users able to edit the (Office)document online, we can get the the link form **webUrl** property of item. Then you can navigate the user to that link so the users able to edit the document.